# Why does the same wifi RTL8821CE work with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but not with Elementary 6?

Tags: wifi, drivers, release-odin

Elementary 6 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS appear to load the same Realtek driver for my card RTL8821CE. On the same laptop, WiFi with Ubuntu works without issue but with Elementary it soon disconnects.

Disregard... WiFi OK now! A few restarts may have helped.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't quite enough information here to hazard an accurate guess, however, as of this moment in time, Ubuntu 20.04 is using the `5.11.0-37-generic` kernel and Elementary OS 6 is using `5.11.0-36-generic`. One difference may be stock Ubuntu's implementation of device discovery.

Try this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Use `ubuntu-drivers` to list already installed devices:

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers list
   ```

   Alternatively, you can show devices that may need drivers like this:

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
   ```
2. If you see a list of items, you may be able to auto-install any missing drivers like this:

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers install
   ```

If this does not resolve the issue with your network device, then we'll need to look through your `/var/log/syslog` file to see why the network may be unstable on Elementary OS